# To extract specific key into a list from JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x

How do i extract the values of **terms** in below JSON into a list in opposite order. In this example i want the output to be `["Auto Ontology","hdfc bank","giftplus card"]`.

```
{
  "faqs": [
    {
      "question": "Can the value of the HDFC Bank Giftplus card be topped up?",
      "alternateQuestions": [

      ],
      "terms": [
        "giftplus card",
        "hdfc bank",
        "Auto Ontology"
      ],
      "tags": [

      ],
      "refId": "7aea18a1-32c8-5af4-8d77-da31f9c7ff26",
      "responseType": "message",
      "answer": [
        {
          "text": "Gifting we believe is special to the occasion and hence you cannot reload this card. Every occasion is a new occasion and deserves a new card.",
          "type": "basic",
          "channel": "default"
        }
      ],
      "alternateAnswers": [

      ]
    },**strong text**
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what specific problems are you having with it? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: print(some_json['faqs'][0]['terms'][::-1])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  {
  "faqs": [
  {
  "question": "Can the value of the HDFC Bank Giftplus card be topped up?",
  "alternateQuestions": [

  ],
  "terms": [
    "giftplus card",
    "hdfc bank",
    "Auto Ontology"
  ],
  "tags": [

  ],
  "refId": "7aea18a1-32c8-5af4-8d77-da31f9c7ff26",
  "responseType": "message",
  "answer": [
    {
      "text": "Gifting we believe is special to the occasion and hence you cannot reload this card. Every occasion is a new occasion and deserves a new card.",
      "type": "basic",
      "channel": "default"
    }
  ],
  "alternateAnswers": [

  ]
}
]
}
```

You can use the python code given below To print opposite order

```
import json
f = open('rev.json', 'r') 
a = json.load(f)
b = a["faqs"][0]["terms"][::-1]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
['Auto Ontology', 'hdfc bank', 'giftplus card']
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use the snippet

```
Var = a["faqs"][0]["terms"][::-1]
```

The `::-1` is used to reverse the output.